# Measure an Android view with accessibility-enabled large font

Tags: android, fonts, accessibility

I have some code that requires to know the size of a view. All works fine with normal font, however there seems to be an issue when the phone has 'large font' selected in the accessibility options. From what I can gather the view's height is returned the same ignoring the larger font.

The complexity comes from the fact that I'm measuring the view with visibility set to View.GONE. This is my current code:

```
v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
final int targetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
```

One thought I had is to detect if large font is enabled and adjust the measured height accordingly but this seems to be a rather clunky solution. Maybe someone else has solved this problem before?

EDIT:

This is the layout that's causing the issue - all declared in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/signup_prompt_wrapper"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/signup_drawer_inner_padding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/signup_drawer_inner_padding"
    android:background="@color/signup_prompt_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/signup_prompt_image_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/signup_drawer_image_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_report_white_24dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/signup_prompt_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/signup_drawer_inner_padding" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup_prompt_dismiss"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="DISMISS" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/signup_prompt_signup"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="SIGN IN" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The text size and scaling are resolved when the view is constructed or when the text appearance is set if you are applying one at run time. It's unlikely that the view is measuring itself against an unscaled text size -- unless it's specified as `dp` (unscaled) instead of `sp`. What type of view are you measuring? How was it created?

Comment: I don't specify the size - only the style `"?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`. The view is a linear layout with an image, text and a couple of buttons. I'll update the question with the layout details.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you measure when the view is VISIBLE?

Comment: No it's measured the same regardless of the visibility.

Comment: @vkislicins I am facing the same issue, Did u get any solution?